# Regular Expression in JavaScript for String Comma Separated

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string as follows

> New York, New York, United States

I need a Regular Expression ether for at least 1 comma or at least 2 comma 
or
A any three words with 2 commas in between .

Comment: _'Give me teh codez'_ questions tend not to do too well on [so]

Comment: I do not get ,what  you want to say ?

Comment: StackOverflow does not write code for you. If this is what you want, try other sites such as fiverr or elance. Please post the code that you have tried and an explanation of why your attempts are not working

Comment: I have used /([a-zA-Z])+(,[a-zA-Z]+)/  and ^[a-zA-Z_,0-9\.]+$

Comment: Why not just split by `/ *, */g` and count the resulting tokens.

Comment: @VikrantVirBhalla you're not matching the spaces. `\s` should do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^[^,\n]+,(?:[^,\n]+,?)*$
```

You can use this.Replace `*` by `{1,2}` if you want only `3` words.See demo.

```
^[^,\n]+,(?:[^,\n]+,?){0,2}$
```

https://regex101.com/r/bW3aR1/11

```
var re = /^[^,\n]+(?:,[^,\n]+)*$/gm;
var str = 'New York, New York, United States\nNew York, New York\nNew York\nNew York, New York, United States,';
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) != null) {
if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
re.lastIndex++;
}
// View your result using the m-variable.
// eg m[0] etc.
}
```

Comment: I used this but this regular expression works for simple string input also , I need for at least 1 comma should be there . if no comma is there it should not work .

Comment: yes string -> asds and string -> asds ,  both are valid but we want is that the string -> asds should be invalid

Comment: Simply a regular expression with at least 1 comma

Comment: It works a bit for me . Can you give me a reference link from where i can study about regular expressions . It would be very help full.

Comment: @VikrantVirBhalla  http://www.regular-expressions.info/  regex101.com http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean